# Return from form to module

Tags: excel, vba, userform

**UPDATE**

Module segment (MessageBox is the userform) :

```
    If fso.FileExists(VidPathFile) Then
        FileExists = True
        GoTo Main:
    End If

Main:
    If FileExists = False Then
        MsgBox "File does not exist"
    Else
        MessageBox.TextBox1.Text = <VidPathFile stat>
        MessageBox.Show
    End If
```

Command button on userform:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Unload Me

End Sub
```

If the file exists, the MessageBox is displayed with the VidPathFile information. When I click CommandButton1, the userform closes and the script ends, which is what I want it to do.

However, the VBE returns to the userform editor. I want it to return to the module editor (if possible).

I also tried `MessageBox.Show vbmodal` but it still returns to the userform editor when the program ends. The userform's "Show Modal" property is set to "True".

Hope this clarifies things.

**ORIGINAL**

In Excel VBA, I'm working on a module that calls a userform.

During testing, I run the module from the VBE. Once I unload the userform (thus ending the program), the VBE returns to the userform editor.

Is there a VBE setting or code that can be placed in a userform or command button event that can return to the module's editor window instead? This will make getting back to editing quicker instead of having to search through the list of modules over and over.

Comment: Closing the edit form (assuming it's modal) shouldn't end the program... are you not calling it modally? Hard to really tell since you didn't include any code in your question.

Comment: I've created `UserForm1`. In `Module1`¸I've created a sub containing `UserForm1.Show`. When I run the sub from `VBE` the form 'shows'. When 'terminating' the form, I get back to the sub's code in `Module1`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: As i said... are you not calling it modally?

Comment: `UserForm1.Show vbModal` - or you can just change the property of the form to modal.

Comment: As far as I know you can't dictate which code module is shown once a procedure ends - I always find if a userform is the last module to execute, the VBE returns you to that module once it's finished. Have you tried using `Me.Hide` instead of unloading the form?